# Gambler's ruin alternative solution

Tags: probability, random-walk

> Consider the gambler's ruin problem. Suppose there are two gamblers $A$ and $B$ and each time, they bet $\$ 1$. If $A$ starts with $\$ i$, calculate the probability that $A$ wins the game (by getting all $N$ dollars). Assume that the probability of winning (resp. losing) a single bet (in any round) is $p$ (resp. $1-p$).

The usual solution defines $P_i = P(A \text{ wins } | A \text{ starts at } \$ \ i)$ and solves for $P_i = p P_{i+1} + q P_{i-1}$ with initial conditions $P_0 = 0, P_N = 1$.

I am curious why we assume $P_i = P(A \text{ wins } | A \text{ starts at } \$ \ i)$ and not $P_i = P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } \$ \ i)$. To do this, let's assume $Q_i = P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } \$ \ i)$ and everything else remains as above.

Then
\begin{align*}
Q_i &= P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } i) \\
&= P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } i, A \text{ wins current round})+ P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } i, A \text{ loses current round}) \\
&= Q_{i+1} + Q_{i-1}
\end{align*}

The initial conditions are $Q_0 = 0, Q_N = 1$. But this certainly does not give a similar solution. Where did I go wrong in constructing the recurrence relation?

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't want to find the probability of $A$ wining and starting with \$$i$ as this isn't the same as the probability of $A$ wining given they start with \$$i$. Additionally the initial value for $Q_N$ is incorrect unless you assume there is a $100$% chance that $A$ starts at \$$N$. (Also the equations look like they are wrong anyway)

Comment: @Fishbane Isn't that how $Q_N$ is defined? That A wins the game AND A starts with all the money, which means, he wins by default. Can you also explain why the recurrence is incorrect?

Comment: @Isa No. $Q_N$ is the probability that $A$ wins the game and starts with all the money as you said, and again it is correct that starting with all the money means they win by default. However that means that $Q_N$ is equal to the probability that $A$ starts with \$$N$. If that isn't $100$% then $Q_N\neq1$. This is because $Q_N$ is not a conditional probability.

Comment: @Isa The recurrence is incorrect for similar reasons. The first two lines of your derivation are correct, but $P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } i, A \text{ wins current round})$ is $\bf not$ $Q_{i+1}$. Again this is because $Q_i$ is not a conditional probability.

Comment: @Fishbane I don't get the "100%" that you're saying. Could you please explain that part in a different way? (Sorry and thanks for helping me out.)

Comment: @Isa I'll try. Let us simplify to the case that $N=1$. In this case there are only $2$ possibilities. Either $A$ starts with \$$1$ and wins by default, or $A$ starts with \$$0$ and loses by default. Clearly therefore $P(A \text{ wins})=P(A \text{ starts at \$}1)$. Additionally $P(A \text{ wins and }A \text{ starts at \$}1)=P(A \text{ starts at \$}1)$ for the same reason. Now assume that the amount $A$ starts with is randomly chosen by flipping a coin, we can now see that $P(A \text{ starts at \$}1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and so $Q_N=P(A \text{ wins and }A \text{ starts at \$}1)=\frac{1}{2}\neq1$.

Comment: @Fishbane Why will the amount that A starts with be random? A starts with $i$ dollars, it's known to us.

Comment: @Isa To be able to help you more it would be helpful to know what your current knowledge on probability is as what you know will change what makes sense. However if you know that $A$ starts with \$$i$ then we know that $P(A \text{ starts at \$}j)=0$ if $j\neq i$. But therefore $P(A \text{ wins and } A \text{ starts at } j)=0$ and so $Q_j=0$.

Comment: @Fishbane I am learning conditional probability. Since we are calculating it recursively, $P(A \text{ wins}, A \text{ starts at } j \neq i)$ is part of the sub-problem in which A has gone from $i$ to $j$ (after a sequence of wins and losses). A starts at $i$ in the original problem, but with each win/loss, A starts at $j$ in each sub-problem. Isn't it so?

Comment: I think the fundamental problem you are having is that you are misunderstanding the difference between $P(A|B)$ and $P(A \text{ and } B)$, these mean very different things. $P(A|B)$ means that under the assumption $B$ is true what is the probability of $A$. $P(A \text{ and } B)$ means what is the probability that both $A$ and $B$ are true. These are often very different. For example if you have $2$ coins, $P(\text{first coin is heads } | \text{ second coin is heads})=\frac{1}{2}$ but $P(\text{first coin is heads and second coin is heads})=\frac{1}{4}$. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Fishbane I understand that. But what you wrote in the previous comment is slightly different I think. You are picking up two different sub-problems of the recursion. Can we say P(A wins the game, A starts with \$ 1, A wins current round) = P(A wins the game, A starts with \$ 2)? In my mind, we can. But it seems we can not.

Comment: It is true that we cannot say $P(A \text{ wins the game and } A \text{ starts with \$}1 \text{ and } A \text{ wins current round}) = P(A \text{ wins the game and } A \text{ starts with \$}2)$. We can say $P(A \text{ wins the game } | \text{ } A \text{ wins current round and } A \text{ starts with \$}1) = P(A \text{ wins the game } | \text{ } A \text{ starts with \$}2)$. This is because, simplifying, conditional probability is the tool that allows you to look at different sub-problems. Assuming that you are learning probability with the help of an instructor, it may help to talk to them.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment might be badly formatted, I can't fix that as it is due to the length of comment boxes. The probabilities are supposed to be paired together.

Comment: @Fishbane No, it's alright I can read that. The problem is, I can't think an example from the sample space that says the two aren't equal. If $(+1,-1,+1,+1, \cdots, +1)$ denotes a sequence of wins (+1) and losses (-1) so as to win the overall game, can you then pick an example that tells the two events *"A wins the game, A starts with 1, A wins current round"* and *"A wins the game, A starts with 2"* are not bijective?

Comment: @Fishbane Also, I will take some time to give it more thought and leave a message if I understand. Thank you for now!

Answer (score -1):

The notation P(A wins|A starts at \$i), abbreviating as $P(A|i)$, means
$$
P(A|i)={P(A,i)\over P(i)}
$$
It is the probability of A winning the game given the probability of A having i dollars. $P(A,i)$ is the joint probability of player A having $i$ dollars and winning the game. Since we are generally not interested in how many dollars the players have, but whether they will win the game given they start at a particular point, $P(A|i)$ is the correct notation here.

You have not supplied any details of your calculation, but if you state that you are using $Q(A,i)$ then you must also supply the probability of the player having that amount of money at the start of the game.

> The initial conditions are Q0=0,QN=1.

No, the initial conditions in your system must contain whether the person has the money or not. You have to supply the probability of them having $N$ dollars as well as the probability of them winning if they have $N$ dollars. That's why your system is not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my questions. It's not that I haven't supplied details of my calculation, rather, what I wrote happens to be my calculation. I am trying to create the recurrence relation with $Q_i = P(A, i)$.

Comment: Yes but you can't do that, you've misunderstood what that means. If you say that you are using $P(A,i)$ you have to supply the initial conditions of how many dollars the gamblers have. It's a bit frustrating seeing the comments above and now you reply again with the same sort of response after I wrote out the explanation for you.